# Publish web projects with msbuild

Tags: msbuild

I get this error message:

```
(SetGenerateManifests target) -> 
  c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(4351,5): error : Publish is only valid for 'Windows Application' or 'Console Application' project types. [E:\myproj\myproj.csproj]
```

running this command line:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild e:\myproj\myproj.csproj /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0 /t:ResolveReferences;Publish /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:Configuration=Release-Dev /p:PublishProfile=myapp-Dev-Web /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:Password=mypass /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0 /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=E:\temp\web-build.txt;Verbosity=Diagnostic
```

before that I run a command line that succeeds:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild e:\mysln.sln
/p:BuildProjectReferences=true  /p:Configuration=Release-Dev
```

Comment: what happens when you go to visual studio command prompt (developer command prompt) and try that same command?

Comment: the same error message...

Answer (score 0):

msbuild cannot be used to deploy web projects.

The publish feature in msbuild seems to be used only for database projects.

The solution is to use MSDEPLOY to deploy web projects.